# Average deviation from several columns based on a single column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my first post on here and I am pretty new to R. 
I have a huge datafile that looks like the example below.

```
> name = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","H"))
>  school = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
>  age = c(10,20,0,30,40,50,60,NA,70)
>  mark = c(100,70,100,50,90,100,NA,50,50)
>  data = data.frame(name=name,school=school,age=age)

name   school   age mark   (many other trait columns)
A      1        10   100
B      1        20    70
C      1        NA   100
D      2        30    50
E      2        40    90
F      2        50   100
G      3        60    NA
H      3        NA    50
H      3        70    50
```

What I need to do is calculate the average of many traits per school and for each trait I want to create to other columns, one with the mean per school for the trait and another one with the average deviation. I also have trait values of "zero" and "NA", which I dont want to include in the mean calculation. The file I need would look like this:

```
name school   age   agemean  agedev  mark   markmean  markdev  (continue for other traits)
A      1      10        15     -5     100     90       10
B      1      20        15      5      70     90      -20
C      1       0        15      0     100     90       10
D      2      30        40    -10      50     80      -30
E      2      40        40      0      90     80       10
F      2      50        40     10     100     80       20
G      3      60        65     -5      NA     50        0
H      3      NA        65      0      50     50        0
H      3      70        65      5      50     50        0
```

I did a search on here and found some similar questions, but I didnt get how to apply to my case. I tried to use the agreggate function, but it is not working. Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good job for `dplyr`. Here's how you could do it if you want to keep all existing rows per school:

```
require(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), -name)

#Source: local data frame [9 x 8]
#Groups: school
#
#  name school age mark age_mean mark_mean    age_sd  mark_sd
#1    A      1  10  100       15        90  7.071068 17.32051
#2    B      1  20   70       15        90  7.071068 17.32051
#3    C      1  NA  100       15        90  7.071068 17.32051
#4    D      2  30   50       40        80 10.000000 26.45751
#5    E      2  40   90       40        80 10.000000 26.45751
#6    F      2  50  100       40        80 10.000000 26.45751
#7    G      3  60   NA       65        50  7.071068  0.00000
#8    H      3  NA   50       65        50  7.071068  0.00000
#9    H      3  70   50       65        50  7.071068  0.00000
```

If you want to reduce each school to a single-row-summary, you can replace `mutate_each` with `summarise_each` in the code above.